# Spring ContextLoaderListener ignores tag

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

I dont know if im missing something ive read a documentation and asked a lot but cant figure why my app is behaving this way.
My web application keeps complaining about
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]`
during start up.

This happens even if my `web.xml` file contents this tags

```
 <context-param>    
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>                
    <param-value>some/nonexisting/path.xml</param-value>         
    </context-param>
```

Heres complete `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <display-name>J2EE Application Example</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <context-param>
    <param-name>contextAppConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/subfolder/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
                <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
                <param-value>1</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value></param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
                <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring security filters -->

</web-app>
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.j2eeapplication</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2eeapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>J2EE Application Example</name>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
        <import resource="webflow-config.xml" />        



</beans>
```

I have problem loading `applicationContext.xml` file and this may be the key to solve it.
Why no matter what contextLoaderListener loads xml file from default path ?

Comment: Be aware that you have different versions of spring, try to keep it on the same lvl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add it to `web.xml` check order of your declaration

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<display-name>AppName</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
  //... 
 </web-app>
```

instead of your `<context-param>` tag

And then put your `applicationContext.xml` into `src->java->resources` that should help.

Be sure that you have `dispatcherServletContext.xml` in your `WEB-INF` the same directory as you have your `web.xml`.

**dispatcherServletContext.xml:**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="yourPackage"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/${pagesPath}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Properly configure your pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>name</name>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.7.10</cxf.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>RondoServer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>{path_to_webxml}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warName>APP_NAME</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> //...other spring dependency on the same lvl
    </dependencies>
  </project>
```

Comment: same result `Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]`

Comment: Did you have any `dispatcherServletContex.xml?` Review my answer again.

Comment: No i didint have any. Ive done what you suggested but runing app on server end up again with same error. Here is now my folder structure  http://clip2net.com/s/7dBn7J

Comment: Thanks sir any further help will bw appreciated

Comment: Sorry to bother you but did you found out sth. problematic ?

Comment: Try to look in your war file that is generated after `mvn clean install` and tell me do you have there those files `applicationContext.xml` and `web.xml` file in correct paths?

Comment: Sorry newbie alert. How do i look into war file. Its binary. If you mean `target` folder no they arent they are in `/WEB-INF/classes` . On more things. My `mvn clean` is failing bacause maven cant delete `target` folder. Is it possible it has to do something with my problem ?

Comment: Hmm... so simply you have wrong maven paths so try to release all processes that holds or points to traget folder and perform `mvn clean` (worst case is to restart computer). Then paste pom file that you have and war plugin configuration especially. `War` file is only archive you can enter there using total commander.

Comment: Ok after a while i have checked things you mentioned. I edited OP and pasted `pom.xml`. In my war package `xml` files are in folder `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: I would like to accept it but it is still not wrking :/

Comment: But did you check content of your war?

Comment: First of all made changes that I pointed you in my answer! Then read my comment below your question. Review a content of your war file and configure war plugin! This is also in my answer.

Comment: Ok i did all you mentioned above. Updated `pom.xml` with content you provided. I kept everything as simple as possible my applicationContext is almost empty but `ContextListener` is still unable find it

Comment: what is your structure of `war` file? it is wrong I suppouse. Please provide it.

Comment: Application context is empty? You mean `web.xml`?

Comment: Look at it to see good configuration of spring application https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/

Comment: ok now i see where was the error. Thanks greatly for your time and help

Comment: Turns out to be probably an Eclipse problem. I tried to contigure dynamic webpage instead of maven project. I started with simple spring hello world. Application behaved like it should but still in the console tomcat was complaining about missing `appcontext.xml`